# How can I make a row in MySQL correspond with another row?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am looking for some help. I am not a developer or programmer, I am an owner of a webshop and I am looking for some help.
In MySQL I have two rows like this:

```
id  | row_X  | Row_Y 
------------------------
1   | 100   | 100
2   | 200   | 500
3   | 300   | 750
4   | 400   | 1000
5   | 500   | 1250
```

What I want is that in mySQL I can update so that if row_x is 1, row_y should be 1,5 -- there is a proportion of 1/1,5 always

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE \`table\` SET Row_Y = 1.5 * row_X`

Comment: Why _store_ `X * 1.5` if you already store `X`? Can't you just calculate it when needed (e.g. in a view, or a computed column, or even directly in the SELECT list or your application)?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you right, you want to set row_y to row_x * 1,5?
To do so for all entries you could do something like that:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `row_y` = `row_x` * 1.5
```

See working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6c534/1